# Follow the name change of "Programmers" to "Software Engineering"

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, wording

In ["our" help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) there are links to programmers.stackexchange.com. I guess this should be changed to reflect [the recent renaming of that site](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8266/65513) to "Software Engineering".

Comment: At first I thought I could edit this as a moderator, but it seems like a Community Manager will have to fix this.

Comment: I changed it, @Simon, but... You really should be able to edit that page. Looks like someone forgot to set a bit when this site was being set up: try it *now...*